# How to send an Array list to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I want to send a string array list from my MainActivity to Creating activity via using intent. but it gives me some error 
I am dealing with it for some time-_-.

This arraylist is for adding some words. I tried putextra(); and putStringArrayListExtra();

**MainActivity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),creating.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("w",Words);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("m", Meanings);
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

**CreatingActivity**

```
private ArrayList<String> Words1;
private ArrayList<String> Meanings1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_creating);

        Words1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Meanings1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Words1 = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("w");
        Meanings1 = intent1.getStringArrayListExtra("m");
```

when I click the button to come to this activity, this error appears:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.content.Intent.getStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing You are missing something it should be like:

```
 Words1 = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("w");
 Meanings1 = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("m");
```

Right? 
And if still you are facing issue try to debug because i think your way is correct.